# How to use named method of module that is nested with helper module in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem to use `helpers` in `Rails`.

Note this code below.

```
module A    
  module B
    extend self

    def method
      "method at module B of A"
    end

  end 
end

module C    
  extend self
  include A
end

class ClassA
  extend C

  class << self
    def method
      B.method
    end
  end

end

p ClassA.method #=> "method at module B of A"
```

It works em Ruby, but doesn’t work as `Rails helper`.

Below is the my files.

`/lib/a/b.rb`

```
module A
  module B
    def method
      "It works"
    end
  end
end
```

`app/helpers/a_helper.rb`

```
require 'a/b'

module AHelper
  include A
end
```

`app/views/a/_form.haml`

```
B.method
```

When i call `B.method` inside `_form.haml` an error is raised: `uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::B`

If set `config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false` in `config/application.rb`, and include `extend AHelper` inside my `controller`, too doesn’t work.